# What are my further steps in creating a deterministic finite automaton?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, regular-language, finite-automata, finite-state-machine

I have to create a Deterministic finite automaton that handles the regular language (0100 + 0001 + 01)* and has a parity bit at the end to make sure 0's are even.

To clarify what I mean by even 0 parity bit, once the finite automaton loops through all possible choices, it determines if the DFA has an even amount of 0's, if there arent, it will add a 0 to the end of the message, else it will add a 1.

E.G. the machine will accept 01000 but not 01001/ 0101001 but not 0101000

I have created an M1 that accepts (0100+0001+01)* [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74TQz.jpg)

And then created a M2 to accept (0100+0001+01)*(0+1). This expression/machine accounts for the parity bit (0+1) [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP10X.jpg)

And then a M3 to accept strings with Even 0s  HERE> i.stack.imgur.com/eyPMk.png

My question is, what do I do next? Do I combine M1 and M3? M2 and M3? Do I take the complement of something?

There is a similar question at

math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760909/where-did-i-go-wrong-creating-a-deterministic-finite-automaton

however, the OP did not (to my knowledge) quite explain what they did to solve it. I am hoping you might be able to.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha$ denote the regular expression $0100 + 0001 + 01$. The language you're actually interested in is that of the regular expression
$$(\alpha\alpha)^*1 + \alpha(\alpha\alpha)^*0,$$
so you could just create a DFA for that language.

But, taking your approach, you should combine $M_2$ (for $\alpha^*(0+1)$) and $M_3$. From those two, you need to build a new DFA that accepts words that are accepted by both automata.

Do you know how to do that? Hint: the states of the new DFA are pairs $(t_2, t_3)$ where $t_2$ is a state of $M_2$ and $t_3$ a state of $M_3$.

Comment: Ok, thank you! So combine M2 and M3. Im not quite sure I know the proper way to build a new DFA that accepts words accepted by both. Would you mind giving a brief tutorial or rundown or link, please?

Comment: The idea is to run both machines at the same time, starting in the combined starting state $(s_2, s_3)$ with $s_i$ the starting state of $M_i$, and taking a transition $(t_2, t_3) \to (t_2', t_3')$ whenever there are transitions $t_i \to t_i'$ in $M_i$ (for the same symbols). Final states are pairs $(t_2, t_3)$ with $t_i$ a final state in $M_i$.